# AngularJS - double ng-repeater and <a> tag strange behaviour

Tags: angularjs

I've run into this issue in an app, and managed to isolate the problem. I have a ng-repeat inside another ng-repeat. And it would work as expected, except for the fact that the `<a>` tag from the outer ng-repeat somehow ends up duplicated inside the inner one. A bit hard to explain so here goes the code:

```
<ul class="nav nav-list">
    <li ng-repeat="item in items">
        <a href="upperLevel.html" >               
            <span >{{item.name}}</span>                     
            <ul >
                <li ng-repeat="menuSubItem in item.menuItems" >
                   This text is wrapped again in the upperLevel a ???
                   <a href="#" >                         
                        <span > {{menuSubItem.name}}</span>
                    </a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

resulting (for the items that have menuItems) in something like this:

```
<li ng-repeat="item in items" class="ng-scope">
        <a href="upperLevel.html">               
            <span class="ng-binding">Test</span>                     
            </a><ul><a href="upperLevel.html">
                </a><!-- ngRepeat: menuSubItem in item.menuItems --><li ng-repeat="menuSubItem in item.menuItems" class="ng-scope"><a href="upperLevel.html">
                   This text is wrapped again in the upperLevel a ???
                   </a><a href="#">                         
                        <span class="ng-binding">----- TestSub3</span>
                    </a>
                </li><li ng-repeat="menuSubItem in item.menuItems" class="ng-scope"><a href="upperLevel.html">
                   This text is wrapped again in the upperLevel a ???
                   </a><a href="#">                         
                        <span class="ng-binding">----- TestSub4</span>
                    </a>
                </li>
            </ul>

    </li>
```

The "This text [...]" part get's wrapped in the outer `<a>`. Doesn't happen if that `<a>` is replaced with a `<div>`. Anyone has an idea why is that happening?

http://jsfiddle.net/68CYt/5/

Comment: I'm not sure, but the way you've organized your markup seems very strange. You have anchor tags that have child anchor tags (Is that even allowed in HTML?). My advice is try using div's and ng-click for your functionality since it seems to work with <div>'s and you'll have a much cleaner HTML structure. Looking at just your HTML code I'm having a hard time understanding what the functionality is, which is never a good sign.

Comment: doubt that `<ul>` is valid child of `<a>`

Comment: The answer fixes the issue for this purpose, but I still don't know why angular started adding those extra tags there (duplicating the outer `<a>` inside) and couldn't find any info on that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It isn't the ng-repeat tag, it's the position of your markup within it: move the closing `</a>` tag up to directly under the span so it looks like this:

```
<li ng-repeat="item in items">
  <a href="upperLevel.html" >               
     <span >{{item.name}}</span>   
  </a>
```

Here's the [full fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/68CYt/7/).

Comment: Hey, thanks for looking at it! I've started from a project with tons of markup and I think i just went dumb :) Thanks a lot!